What is the control state for a Controlled-RY gate?
I am trying to understand Qiskit's control gates.  For example, the CRY gate requires an input as the control state (ctrl_state).
If I use two qubits in a simple circuit, I can define ctrl_state='1' or ctrl_state='0'.  What is the difference between the two options, and how do their matrix representations differ?
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit_aer import StatevectorSimulator
import numpy as np

x0 = 0.86
x1 = 0.45
x2 = 0.11
x3 = 0.81
xlist = np.array([x0, x1, x2, x3])
xlist = xlist/np.linalg.norm(xlist)  # initial state
theta1 = 0.254

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.prepare_state(Statevector(xlist), [0, 1])
circ.cry(theta1, 0, 1, ctrl_state='0')
# circ.cry(theta2, 0, 1, ctrl_state='1')

simulator = StatevectorSimulator()
job = qk.transpile(circ, simulator)  # execute circuit on qasm simulator
result = simulator.run(job,shots=128).result()  # results from the job
out_state = result.get_statevector()
print(np.array(out_state))
circ.draw(output='mpl')



Just realised you asked about matrix representations as well. I'll update my answer.

Since @diemilio gave a nice answer with operator representations, I'll leave it for now.

If ctrl_state=1, then the controlled $RY$ gets applied to the target qubit if the control qubit is in state $|1\rangle$.
Similarly, if ctrl_state=0, then the controlled $RY$ gets applied to the target qubit if the control qubit is in state $|0\rangle$.
This can be seen very naturally when you express these gates in their matrix form.
For the matrix with ctrl_state=1, you have:
$$CRY = I\otimes|0\rangle\langle0| + RY\otimes|1\rangle\langle1|$$
For the matrix with ctrl_state=0, you have:
$$\bar{C}RY = RY\otimes|0\rangle\langle0| + I\otimes|1\rangle\langle1|$$

The control state defines the value of $q_0$ that is needed to trigger the action of the $\text{Ry}$ gate. This is typically assumed to be $|1\rangle$ unless stated otherwise.
However setting ctrl_state = '0' means the control state for the $\text{CRy}$ gate is now $|0\rangle$.
You can understand this as ...
"If $q_0$ is in the state $|0\rangle$, apply $\text{Ry}$. Otherwise do nothing (perform the identity)".
We can achieve the same effect by setting the control state to $|1\rangle$ and doing a Pauli $X$ on the control qubit on before and after the $\text{Ry}$ gate is applied.
A $\text{CRy}$ controlled with control state $|0\rangle$ (denoted by empty circle)

is equivalent to a $\text{CRy}$ with control state $|1\rangle$ conjugated with some $X$ gates.

Just as an example consider the truth table for the $\text{CX}$ gate. Note that we are implicitly assuming the control state is $|1\rangle$ here.
$$
\begin{align} 
\text{CX}|00\rangle &= |00\rangle \\
\text{CX}|01\rangle &= |01\rangle \\
\text{CX}|10\rangle &= |11\rangle \\
\text{CX}|11\rangle &= |10\rangle \\
\end{align}
$$
We can summarise the table above as... "If the control qubit is in the state $|1\rangle$, then flip the target qubit. Otherwise do nothing". The idea of a control state just generalises this notion for states other than $|1\rangle$.
We are often accustomed to using the "all $|1\rangle$" state as the control state in many cases but this need not be the case. In fact if we have a gate with $k$ control qubits, then our control state could be any $k$-bit string.
